# MySQL Insert

Tags: mysql

Вопрос по поводу конструкции INSERT. Что быстрей отработает INSERT ... VALUES, в котором отправляется сразу 20 строчек, или 20 раз по INSERT ... SET? Или будет происходить одно и то же действие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 большой запрос почти всегда отработает быстрее, чем 20 маленьких)

Тем более если из php отправлять

Answer (score 0):

По личному опыту:

```
  START TRANSACTION;
       INSERT INTO table VALUES();
       INSERT INTO table VALUES();
       INSERT INTO table VALUES();
       INSERT INTO table VALUES();
  COMMIT;
  //    ~=
  INSERT INTO table VALUES (
        (...),
        (...),
        (...)
  )
```

Но в коде в этом случае естественно лучше использовать один запрос, но если будет необходимость - использовав транзакции вы сможете значительно ускорить скорость работы вашего скрипта.